# Get Notified when files have been edited in a specific folder using UNIX "Find"

Tags: bash, shell, find

Im looking for an extra layer of protection on my ad server to ensure that there have been no file edits that i am unaware of.

Iv been using the following command to check and see if any of the files have been edited in the past 7 days.

```
find /home/adserve/public_html/ads/www /home/adserve/public_html/ads/plugins -mtime -7
```

But i was thinking of adding this to a small shell script then have cron run it once a day, but how can i get it to notify me via email if there have been any edits ?

If nothing has been changed the command doesn't output anything but if something has it outputs those specific files. Can i get it to email me these if found ?

Comment: Don't forget that intruders can change the modify time on files.  You should probably think in terms of generating a hash (SHA3, SHA2-256) of the files and recording those, and then later comparing them.  Remember to update the hashes after pushing new versions of the files.   Yes, you can email the results.  `mailx -s "Changed files" username@example.com` is a basic command that will read the message from standard input (eg, the output of `find`).  Experiment with empty inputs.  You may need to configure the mail delivery mechanism.

Comment: Expanding on what Jonathan Leffler said, the baseline hashes need to be stored off the host, otherwise the intruder will be able to modify them as well, and you will still have gained nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of `cron` is to send an email if the command produces some output. That means you can just add the above command to your crontab. If you want to send the emails to specific email addresses, you can use the *environment setting* `MAILTO`. For example:

```
MAILTO="foobar@example.com"
# run five minutes after midnight, every day
5 0 * * * find /home/... -mtime -7
```

Comment: Is there a way i can only send emails for this cron ? I have other things in my crontab but only need the output of the "find" command.

Comment: @Analog: If you do not want to receive emails for some cron entries, then suppress the output with redirection, i.e. append `> /dev/null 2>&1` to the command.